# Как прижать div к верху

Tags: html, css

Составил такую структуру, и появилась проблема при большом количестве текста. Боковые блоки не прижимаются к верху экрана.

Как возможно решить этот мой косяк?

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: #ddf;
  float: left;
  width: 285px;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.col3 {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="col1">
    Column1
    <br>Column1
    <br>Column1
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
  </div>
  <div class="col3">Column3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.col1 {
  background-color: #ddf;
  width: 285px;
}

.col2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.col3 {
  background-color: cyan;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="col1">
    Column1
    <br>Column1
    <br>Column1
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
    <br>This is an example of a div that contains a series of very long run on sentences.
  </div>
  <div class="col3">Column3</div>
</div>
```

убрать `float`

Comment: =) Спасибо большое.